# c# how do I create a custom div after i submit my input on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

After submitting what I have entered into the `input` tag, I want a `div` containing the data I typed into the input tag to appear below the `<input>` tag on the same page. What should I do?

```
<input class="form-control" id="myComment" placeholder="Add a comment" type="text">
                                    <button id="submitCommentBtn">Button</button>
<div id="appearHere"></div>
```

Comment: If that's all you want to do, you could use JavaScript without posting back to the server. But assuming you want to do something else as well on the server with the data (e.g. maybe save it somewhere), then you need to write some C#. Unfortunately what precisely you need to write we don't know because a) you didn't show any of your existing server side code so that we could fit an example into your scenario, and b) we don't know what sort of asp.net site you've got - there are several different types such as WebForms, MVC, Razor Pages. The precise solution would depend on that.